# Only show most recent records based on date column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, show

I have a table with columns for students, grades etc. and a column for a respective date (not the created_at date). In my models, a student has_many scores and a score belongs_to a student. When a user clicks on a student, I'd like the show page to only display the most recent grade and related date, based on the dates entered in the the 'fielded' column.

Currently my show view looks like this:

```
 <% @scores.each do |score| %>
 <p>
   <b>Grade:</b>
    <%= score.grade %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <b>Date:</b>
    <%= score.fielded %>
 </p>
 <% end %>
```

---

My Students controller looks like this:

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @scores = @student.scores
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @student }
  end
end
```

---

The scores database has this in it:

```
class CreateScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :scores do |t|
       t.string :student   
       t.integer :score
       t.date :fielded
       t.string :grade
       t.integer :student_id

       t.timestamps
     end
   end
end
```

---

Currently, the code I have shows me all grades and dates associated with that student. When I try to change the view code

```
@scores.each do |score|
```

to

```
@scores.order('fielded DESC') do |score|
```

it gives me no results. I know that this alone won't solve the problem, but I'm not sure why this isn't working either. Ultimately, I'd like it to only show the most recent value. I'm not all that experienced with Rails so any suggestions on how to move forward or change my code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@scores.order('fielded DESC').each do |score|
```

The `each` method is what allows you to yield your code block (inside do) to each item in the `@scores` collection. The `order` clause modifies the results of the collection but is not itself yield to the block.

Comment: That worked - thanks! Any chance you know how to make only the most recent one from that ordered list appear in the view?

Comment: `@scores.order(...).limit(1)` is one way to do it. All this and more is well documented. Check out the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: That worked as well, thanks so much! I'll definitely look through the guide - apologies for not looking through that first!